# Codename one file chooser dialog

Tags: android, codenameone, jfilechooser, filechooser

Does CodenameOne expose a file chooser UI component that is similar to JFileChooser in Swing. If so, could you direct me to a place I could read some more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile devices don't really have a file system or a file chooser.

There is a new cn1lib that provides something similar to a file chooser for Codename One, it's available in the extensions menu already. We have a blog post coming up about it tomorrow in the publish queue:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/

Comment: Fantastic, I'll wait for the blog post.